# Link 2 items SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have 2 SharePoint lists - List 1 for requests then at some point the request is copied to List 2.
Once the process on List 2 is completed I want the original item on List 1 to automatically remove the permissions to that item on List 1.

I have looked at using Power Automate Get Items option using a unique ref no (that copies the ID no for List 1) but that is not really a viable option since it is hard to limit the amount of items it has to look through since there is no obvious grouping of items to filter the query.

Is there some way to explicitly link the 2 items so that Power Automate knows exactly which item to stop sharing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a lookup column on list 2 which uses list 1 as a source. When you copy the list item to list 2, you would need to set the lookup column to the ID of the original item in list 1.

This way, you can use that ID value to find the correct item in list 1 via Power Automate.

Comment: You would either utilise an action on the SharePoint connector or make a HTTP call to SharePoint. If you're using the out of the box list item ID, there are some API calls that make this fairly easy to do.

Comment: Removed my last comment since turns out the first suggestion was correct I misunderstood how it would work. Thanks for helping